# Initializing a collection

Tags: java

What is the difference between the following two statements, in initializing an `ArrayList`?

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: well. first one was allowed in java 6 whereas second one is allowed in java 7, I am also curious to know the detailed reason for it

Comment: @PrasadKharkar you mean "the _second one_ is not allowed in java 6", right?

Comment: @fge yeah made silly mistake while commenting. I mean. java 6 doesn't allow second version and java 7 allows it.

Comment: But isn't there any detailed explanation for this? Or is it just the syntax change? Is this only the difference?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar this is due to type inference ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)), which is new in Java 7

Comment: Also read [this](http://tronicek.blogspot.in/2011/03/do-we-really-need-in-diamond-operator.html) blog.

Comment: thanks fge and The New Idiot. Will study thoroughly :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before Java 1.7, only this one is permitted:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And in 1.7, this is added, which is the same but shorter: (all programmers are lazy)

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: +1 for "all programmers are lazy". Best example the self explaining variable `a` ;-)

Comment: @Chasmo +1 for you comment too..

Comment: Actually known as "Diamond Operator" in Java 7 >.

Comment: Why not just do away with the diamonds on the RHS if it's inferred?

Comment: Compatibility. It meant another thing (raw type).

Answer (score 4):

The latter uses an inferred type introduced in Java 7. The syntax (known as diamond operator) is illegal for Collections before Java 1.7 so the former is used for those earlier versions.

The diamond operator reduces the verbosity of the declaration.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. The second option (called Diamond Operator) is a shortcut. The compiler will infer that the type parameter of the generic ArrayList must be String.

Answer (score 0):

Second option was uses a concept that was introduced in java 7 - inferred types. Apart from that and assuming you are using java 7 the effect of the two calls should be the same. On earlier java versions you can not use second version of your code.